# Workaround for Viber and libcurl3 on Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: 18.04, viber

For those of you looking for a workaround to make Viber coexist with other apps like Opera and Virtualbox depending on libcurl4 and uninstalling your Viber client, here's a workaround:

Visit Viber website, download the rpm version (Fedora) and convert the rpm package to deb using alien:

```
sudo apt-get install alien

sudo alien --to-deb --scripts viber.rpm
```

Install the package:

```
sudo dpkg -i viber_7.0.0.1035-3_amd64.deb
```

I hope it helps.

Comment: For better rating you should separate your question with answer to 2 parts - question and answer.

Comment: This helped me with a dependency requirement for libcurl3 under Ubuntu 18.04 LTS which uses libcurl4. The package was Synergy 1.6.2. Thanks!!!

Comment: Please move your answer to the appropriate answer section. See also [Can I answer my own question?](https://askubuntu.com/help/self-answer)

Answer (score 2):

> *Since Claudio didn't moved his answer post as a new answer, I opened a new >answer post. Otherwise this question is still seen as question without answer, which is not true.
>
>   @claudio: Post your answer as separate and flag this answer as to be deleted*

## workaround to make Viber coexist with other apps

- like Opera and Virtualbox depending on libcurl4 and uninstalling your Viber client, here's a workaround:

Visit Viber website, download the rpm version (Fedora) and convert the rpm package to deb using alien:

```
sudo apt-get install alien
sudo alien --to-deb --scripts viber.rpm
```

Install the package:

```
sudo dpkg -i viber_7.0.0.1035-3_amd64.deb
```

I hope it helps.